# How to save multiple values of checkboxes into one column of mongodb using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I have a list of checkboxes, each representing a day of the week, however when I click them and add it to my mongoDB database, they come as separate items. I need to somehow append them into one array.

```
5: {name: "days", value: "Sunday"}
6: {name: "days", value: "Monday"}
7: {name: "days", value: "Tuesday"}
```

This is what I get, and what i want instead is below:

```
(3) ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"]
```

When I run a function like this, it simply takes the last value (in this case Tuesday)

```js
var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
console.log(unindexed_array);
var data = {}


$.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
  data[n['name']] = n['value']
})
```

```html
<div class="days" id="days">
  <label>Repeat every:</label>                
  <div class="checkbox_freq">                                    
    <input id="sunday" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" name="days"  <%= user.days.includes("Sunday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="sunday">Sunday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="monday" type="checkbox" value="Monday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Monday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="monday">Monday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="tuesday" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Tuesday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="wednesday" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Wednesday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="thursday" type="checkbox" value="Thursday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Thursday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="thursday">Thursday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="friday" type="checkbox" value="Friday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Friday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="friday">Friday</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_freq">
    <input id="saturday" type="checkbox" value="Saturday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Saturday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <label for="saturday">Saturday</label>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is how I am taking the response to update the fields.

Please note, the array is perfectly formed while "Creating a new user" but when I go to update it, I am not able to update the array to the new array.

Comment: you didn't read the doc correctly, the serializeArray method works with a form, and it is based on names, not IDs

Comment: Oh, hmm, makes sense. So how do I fix this?

Comment: I do not understand; you mean that the doc on jQuery, (with example) is not clear or that an identical question has never been asked here?